# find the rank of a linear mapping such that $T^2=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\Bbb R^6\to\Bbb R^6$ be a linear mapping such that $T^2=0$.Then which one is true?

a)Rank$(T)$ is less than or equal to 3

b)Rank$(T)$ is greater than  3

c)Rank$(T)$ is  equal to 5

d)Rank$(T)$ is less than or equal to 6

> I think, Rank of $T^2$ and Rank of $T$ are less than 6 since $T^2=0$ ...
>   So d) may be false...Now How to proceed?Someone please explain...

Comment: Since you need just one correct answer, what happens if $T\equiv0$?

Comment: $d$ must be true.

Comment: how is d) false from your reasoning?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$T^2=0$ implies $\text{Im}(T)\subseteq\text{ker}(T)$. Note that $\text{dim Im}(T)+\text{dim ker}(T)=6$ and $\text{dim Im}(T)\leq \text{dim ker}(T)$, we have that $\text{dim Im}(T)\leq 3$.

Comment: :Could u plz explain" $T^2=0$ implies $\text{Im}(T)\subseteq\text{ker}(T)$"

Comment: Suppose $v\in \text{Im}(T)$. Then $v=T(w)$ for some $w\in V$, and $T(v)=T^2(w)=0$. So $v\in\text{ker}(T)$.

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ had rank larger than $3$, then its kernel would have dimension at most $2$ (Rank-nullity theorem). Can $T^2=T(T)=0$ then?

Answer (score -1):

It could clearly seen that in Transformation $T^2$ that the Range of $T$ acts as the Domain for the other $T$. It's given that $T^2=0$, hence the $\operatorname{Rank}(T) \subseteq \operatorname{NullSpace}(T)$. Thus we know that 
$$\operatorname{Basis}\big(\operatorname{Rank}(T)\big) \subseteq \operatorname{Basis}\big(\operatorname{Nullspace}(T)\big)
$$ 
and hence $$\dim(\operatorname{Rank}(T)) \le \dim(\operatorname{Nullspace}(T))$$
And now by the **Rank-Nulity** Theorem we know that 
$$
\begin{split}
\operatorname{Rank}(T)+&\operatorname{Nullspace}(T)=6\\
&\qquad\Downarrow\\
&\operatorname{Rank}(T) \le 3
\end{split}
$$